# There exists a continuous function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ unbounded???

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am studying Real Analysis and I had a exam last week. In that test there  was the question below:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a non compact set. Show that there exists continuous function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ is unbounded.

So I tried to show that if every $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous is bounded then $U$ is compact.

I have proved that $U$ is bounded, but how can I prove that $U$ is closed??? 
It's just for curiosity because the test was last week.

Comment: What if $U=\mathbb R$? Can you think of an unbounded continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? What's your favourite continuous function on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: This is trivial, it is the identity. I have thought this but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**: If $a\in\Bbb R^n$ is in the closure of $U$ but not in $U$, consider the function $f(x) = 1/\|x-a\|$.